# Cannot read property 'category' of undefined (Error)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm pretty new to javascript, and I've been following a tutorial to create an e-commerce website. For some reason I am now getting a TypeError: Cannot read property 'category' of undefined error in reference to:

```
export const listProducts = ({category = '' }) => async (dispatch)
```

part of my productAction.js document. I've included the rest of my productAction.js document below, as well as the other important documents. I would really appreciate any help or guidance on this issue.

productAction.js

```
import Axios from 'axios';
import {
  PRODUCT_CREATE_FAIL,
  PRODUCT_CREATE_REQUEST,
  PRODUCT_CREATE_SUCCESS,
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST,
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
  PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
  PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
  PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
  PRODUCT_UPDATE_REQUEST,
  PRODUCT_UPDATE_SUCCESS,
  PRODUCT_UPDATE_FAIL,
  PRODUCT_DELETE_REQUEST,
  PRODUCT_DELETE_FAIL,
  PRODUCT_DELETE_SUCCESS,
  PRODUCT_REVIEW_CREATE_REQUEST,
  PRODUCT_REVIEW_CREATE_SUCCESS,
  PRODUCT_REVIEW_CREATE_FAIL,
  PRODUCT_CATEGORY_LIST_SUCCESS,
  PRODUCT_CATEGORY_LIST_REQUEST,
  PRODUCT_CATEGORY_LIST_FAIL,
  /*PRODUCT_SAVE_REQUEST,*/
} from '../constants/productConstants';


  export const listProducts = ({name = '', category = '' }) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
  });
  try {
    const { data } = await Axios.get(`/api/products?name=${name}category=${category}`);
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL, payload: error.message });
  }
};

export const listProductCategories = () => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: PRODUCT_CATEGORY_LIST_REQUEST,
  });
  try {
    const { data } = await Axios.get(`/api/products/categories`);
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_CATEGORY_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_CATEGORY_LIST_FAIL, payload: error.message });
  }
};

export const detailsProduct = (productId) => async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST, payload: productId });
    try {
      const { data } = await Axios.get(`/api/products/${productId}`);
      dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS, payload: data });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
        payload:
          error.response && error.response.data.message
            ? error.response.data.message
            : error.message,
      });
    }
  }; 
  export const createProduct = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_CREATE_REQUEST });
    const {
      userSignin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();
    try {
      const { data } = await Axios.post(
        '/api/products',
        {},
        {
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
        }
      );
      dispatch({
        type: PRODUCT_CREATE_SUCCESS,
        payload: data.product,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message;
      dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_CREATE_FAIL, payload: message });
    }
  };
  export const updateProduct = (product) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_UPDATE_REQUEST, payload: product });
    const {
      userSignin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();
    try {
      const { data } = await Axios.put(`/api/products/${product._id}`, product, {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
      });
      dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_UPDATE_SUCCESS, payload: data });
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message;
      dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_UPDATE_FAIL, error: message });
    }
  };
  export const deleteProduct = (productId) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DELETE_REQUEST, payload: productId });
    const {
      userSignin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();
    try {
      const {data} = Axios.delete(`/api/products/${productId}`, {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
      });
      dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DELETE_SUCCESS });
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message;
      dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DELETE_FAIL, payload: message });
    }
  };


  export const createReview = (productId, review) => async (
    dispatch,
    getState
  ) => {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_REVIEW_CREATE_REQUEST });
    const {
      userSignin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();
    try {
      const { data } = await Axios.post(
        `/api/products/${productId}/reviews`,
        review,
        {
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
        }
      );
      dispatch({
        type: PRODUCT_REVIEW_CREATE_SUCCESS,
        payload: data.review,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message;
      dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_REVIEW_CREATE_FAIL, payload: message });
    }
  };
```

productReducer.js

```
const {
    PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
    PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
    PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
    PRODUCT_CATEGORY_LIST_REQUEST,
    PRODUCT_CATEGORY_LIST_SUCCESS,
    PRODUCT_CATEGORY_LIST_FAIL,
  } = require('../constants/productConstants');
  
  export const productListReducer = (
    state = { loading: true, products: [] },
    action
  ) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST:
        return { loading: true };
      case PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS:
        return { loading: false, products: action.payload };
      case PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL:
        return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };

  export const productCategoryListReducer = (
    state = { loading: true, products: [] },
    action
  ) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case PRODUCT_CATEGORY_LIST_REQUEST:
        return { loading: true };
      case PRODUCT_CATEGORY_LIST_SUCCESS:
        return { loading: false, categories: action.payload };
      case PRODUCT_CATEGORY_LIST_FAIL:
        return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };
```

Backend

productModel.js

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    comment: { type: String, required: true },
    rating: { type: Number, required: true },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    image: { type: String, required: true },
    brand: { type: String, required: true },
    category: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    price: { type: Number, required: true },
    countInStock: { type: Number, required: true },
    rating: { type: Number, required: true },
    numReviews: { type: Number, required: true },
    reviews: [reviewSchema],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);

export default Product;
```

productRouter.js

```
import express from 'express';
import expressAsyncHandler from 'express-async-handler';
import data from '../data.js';
import Product from '../models/productModel.js';
import { isAdmin, isAuth } from '../utils.js';

const productRouter = express.Router();

productRouter.get(
  '/',
 expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const name = req.query.name || '';
    const category = req.query.category || '';
    const nameFilter = name ? { name: { $regex: name, $options: 'i' } } : {};
    const categoryFilter = category ? { category } : {};
    const products = await Product.find({
    ...nameFilter,
    ...categoryFilter,
  }).res.send(products);
  })
);

productRouter.get(
  '/categories',
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const categories = await Product.find().distinct('category');
    res.send(categories);
  })
);

productRouter.get(
  '/seed',
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    // await Product.remove({});
    const createdProducts = await Product.insertMany(data.products);
    res.send({ createdProducts });
  })
);

productRouter.get(
  '/:id',
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id);
    if (product) {
      res.send(product);
    } else {
      res.status(404).send({ message: 'Product Not Found' });
    }
  })
);
productRouter.post(
    '/',
    isAuth,
    isAdmin,
    expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
      const product = new Product({
        name: 'sample name ' + Date.now(),
        image: '/images/p1.jpg',
        price: 0,
        category: 1,
        brand: 'sample brand',
        countInStock: 0,
        rating: 0,
        numReviews: 0,
        description: 'sample description',
      });
      const createdProduct = await product.save();
      res.send({ message: 'Product Created', product: createdProduct });
    })
  );


  productRouter.put(
    '/:id',
    isAuth,
    isAdmin,
    expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
      const productId = req.params.id;
      const product = await Product.findById(productId);
      if (product) {
        product.name = req.body.name;
        product.price = req.body.price;
        product.image = req.body.image;
        product.category = req.body.category;
        product.brand = req.body.brand;
        product.countInStock = req.body.countInStock;
        product.description = req.body.description;
        const updatedProduct = await product.save();
        res.send({ message: 'Product Updated', product: updatedProduct });
      } else {
        res.status(404).send({ message: 'Product Not Found' });
      }
    })
  );
export default productRouter;
```

Update:

So, I think the issue was my listProducts constant. In my HomeScreen.js document (not previously included), I realized that I had forgot to add {} within dispatch(listProducts());

```
useEffect(() =>{
        dispatch(listProducts({}));
    }, [dispatch]);
```

My only issue is that while my page now loads, I now have a Request failed with status code 500 error.

I've included the rest of my HomeScreen.js document and my other documents that include listProducts. Any additional guidance would be greatly appreciated.

HomeScreen.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Product from '../components/Product';
import LoadingBox from '../components/LoadingBox';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { listProducts } from '../actions/productActions';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

 export default function HomeScreen() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const productList = useSelector((state) => state.productList);
    const { loading, error, products } = productList;
    useEffect(() =>{
        dispatch(listProducts({}));
    }, [dispatch]);
  return (
    <div>
        {loading ? (
        <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
      ) : error ? (
        <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
      ) : (
        <>
          {products.length === 0 && <MessageBox>No Product Found</MessageBox>}
          <div className="row center">
            {products.map((product) => (
              <Product key={product._id} product={product}></Product>
            ))}
          </div>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

SearchScreen.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { listProducts } from '../actions/productActions';
import LoadingBox from '../components/LoadingBox';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';
import Product from '../components/Product';

export default function SearchScreen(props) {
  const { name = 'all', category = 'all' } = useParams();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const productList = useSelector((state) => state.productList);
  const { loading, error, products } = productList;

  const productCategoryList = useSelector((state) => state.productCategoryList);
  const {
    loading: loadingCategories,
    error: errorCategories,
    categories,
  } = productCategoryList;
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(
      listProducts({
        name: name !== 'all' ? name : '',
        category: category !== 'all' ? category : '',
      })
    );
  }, [category, dispatch, name]);

  const getFilterUrl = (filter) => {
    const filterCategory = filter.category || category;
    const filterName = filter.name || name;
    return `/search/category/${filterCategory}/name/${filterName}`;
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="row">
        {loading ? (
          <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
        ) : error ? (
          <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
        ) : (
          <div>{products.length} Results</div>
        )}
      </div>
      <div className="row top">
        <div className="col-1">
          <h3>Department</h3>
          {loadingCategories ? (
            <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
          ) : errorCategories ? (
            <MessageBox variant="danger">{errorCategories}</MessageBox>
          ) : (
            <ul>
              {categories.map((c) => (
                <li key={c}>
                  <Link
                    className={c === category ? 'active' : ''}
                    to={getFilterUrl({ category: c })}
                  >
                    {c}
                  </Link>
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          )}
        </div>
        <div className="col-3">
          {loading ? (
            <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
          ) : error ? (
            <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
          ) : (
            <>
              {products.length === 0 && (
                <MessageBox>No Product Found</MessageBox>
              )}
              <div className="row center">
                {products.map((product) => (
                  <Product key={product._id} product={product}></Product>
                ))}
              </div>
            </>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

ProductListScreen.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import {
    createProduct,
    deleteProduct,
    listProducts,
  } from '../actions/productActions';
import LoadingBox from '../components/LoadingBox';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';
import {
    PRODUCT_CREATE_RESET,
    PRODUCT_DELETE_RESET,
  } from '../constants/productConstants';

export default function ProductListScreen(props) {
  const productList = useSelector((state) => state.productList);
  const { loading, error, products } = productList;
  const productCreate = useSelector((state) => state.productCreate);
  const {
    loading: loadingCreate,
    error: errorCreate,
    success: successCreate,
    product: createdProduct,
  } = productCreate;
  const productDelete = useSelector((state) => state.productDelete);
  const {
    loading: loadingDelete,
    error: errorDelete,
    success: successDelete,
  } = productDelete;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (successCreate) {
        dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_CREATE_RESET });
        props.history.push(`/product/${createdProduct._id}/edit`);
      }
    if (successDelete) {
        dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DELETE_RESET });
      }
    dispatch(listProducts());
    /// TODO: dispatch delete action
 }, [createdProduct, dispatch, props.history, successCreate, successDelete]);

const deleteHandler = (product) => {
  if (window.confirm('Are you sure to delete?')) {
    dispatch(deleteProduct(product._id));
  }
  };
  const createHandler = () => {
    dispatch(createProduct());
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="row">
        <h1>Products</h1>
        <button type="button" className="primary" onClick={createHandler}>
          Create Product
        </button>
      </div>
      {loadingDelete && <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>}
      {errorDelete && <MessageBox variant="danger">{errorDelete}</MessageBox>}
      {loadingCreate && <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>}
      {errorCreate && <MessageBox variant="danger">{errorCreate}</MessageBox>}
      {loading ? (
        <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
      ) : error ? (
        <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
      ) : (
        <table className="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>NAME</th>
              <th>PRICE</th>
              <th>CATEGORY</th>
              <th>BRAND</th>
              <th>ACTIONS</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {products.map((product) => (
              <tr key={product._id}>
                <td>{product._id}</td>
                <td>{product.name}</td>
                <td>{product.price}</td>
                <td>{product.category}</td>
                <td>{product.brand}</td>
                <td>
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="small"
                    onClick={() =>
                      props.history.push(`/product/${product._id}/edit`)
                    }
                  >
                    Edit
                  </button>
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="small"
                    onClick={() => deleteHandler(product)}
                  >
                    Delete
                  </button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Seems you may be calling `listProducts` and not passing any argument. Can you share where `listProducts` is called/dispatched?

Comment: I think you're right and listProducts is actually the issue. I've updated the question and added additional documents that contain listProducts.

Comment: Just so I understand what you are saying, you call `listProducts({})` with empty object argument and you are seeing a server 500 error from the result of `Axios.get(\`/api/products?name=${name}category=${category}\`)` empty strings you sent? In other words, your GET request looks like "/api/products?name=category="? Can you confirm the request url? It seems like the issue is either in what you send to the API, or how the API handles what was sent.

Answer (score 1):

SO the most plausible answer according to me is (based on the error provided),

The error is causing because you are not passing anything. Due to which the javascript is trying to spread nothing and giving you the error "Cannot read property 'category' of undefined".

I know this is a bit confusing let me explain it with an example

let's say you have a function

```
const test = ({context = ""}) => {
    console.log(context)
}
```

and if you call the `test` function without passing an object like below

```
test();
```

this will produce the error "Cannot read property 'category' of undefined" as the function definition is trying to spread an object and get a context property out of that object but you are passing nothing.

instead, if you call the function

```
test({});
```

or

```
test({context=1});
```

this will not cause you any error as function definition will get an object to spread.

for more details on object spread syntax, you can refer [MDN docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Hope its helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error it seems you may be calling `listProducts` and not passing any argument. If this is expected then you can provide an initial value for the argument to destructure `category` from.

```
export const listProducts = ({ category = '' } = {}) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
  });
  try {
    const { data } = await Axios.get(`/api/products?category=${category}`);
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL, payload: error.message });
  }
};
```